# AngularJS - How to load ng-view based on the URL?

Tags: angularjs

I have been following the AngularJS tutorials on CodeSchool.

So I have `views/index.html` which contains all of my boilerplate code that is identical for each page. Then my templates for each page are in `views/templates/` which I want included in the `index.html` page. So when the home page loads, it loads the `views/index.html` and includes the `views/templates/index.html`.

- views/

  - index.html
  - templates/

    - index.html
    - contact.html
    - about.html

Currently I have

```
    <div id="menu">
        <a id="menu_home" href="/#/index" ng-click="menu.set(0)" ng-class="{current:menu.isSet(0)}">Home</a>
        <a id="menu_hire" href="/#/hire" ng-click="menu.set(1)" ng-class="{current:menu.isSet(1)}">For Hire</a>
        <a id="menu_info" href="/#/info" ng-click="menu.set(2)" ng-class="{current:menu.isSet(2)}">Info</a>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
```

which works great. So only the required html is requested and inserted into the page.

But my problem is that the URL doesn't change in the browser. So if a user went directly to `mysite.com/contact` it wouldn't work. How can I load the page correctly if the `mysite.com/contact` or `mysite.com/about` pages are accessed directly?

I have also got it working using the `ngRoute` module, but the same issue remains when a user goes directly to a page.

Thanks.

Comment: u can use angular ui-router

Comment: Are you using $stateProvider or $urlProvider ?

Comment: @AmitSirohiya I used $routeProvider from the ngRoute module.

Comment: Try to make a plunker if you can so i can help better.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ngRoute and $routeProvider similar to the following.

```
var navigationRoutes = angular.module('navigationRoutes', ['ngRoute']);

/**
 * Load routes for navigation using ngRoute
 */
navigationRoutes.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/index', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/index/index.view.html',
            controller: 'IndexCtrl'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/contact/contact.view.html',
            controller: 'ContactCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/dashboard'
        });
});
```

This way you can also specify a different controller based on the URL.

UPDATE

In your index page if you add -

```
<div class="view">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

To your main index.html page the the contents of the $routeProvider selected file will be shown within this div. You just need to make sure that you add the  tag for the controller.js files in the index.html page.

Comment: But what if a user accesses say the Contact page directly i.e. not through the home page (e.g. bookmarks the page)? They would end up seeing only the component? None of the solutions I've read on Angular routing appear to answer this.

Comment: The same goes for refreshing the page. A new request is sent to the server using the current URL which leads to a component.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make these settings in the web server to redirect all urls to your index page where you load your angular app which in turn will handles the routes